# Bad receiver type 'NSMutableArray *__strong *' error

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to add an object to an NSMutableArray:

```
[eyelidDiagnosis addObject: self.labelDescriptions[biggestBlob.getLabel()]];
```

I'm getting this error on the the line above:

> Bad receiver type 'NSMutableArray *__strong *'

This is the declaration of the array:

```
NSMutableArray *eyelidDiagnosis[5];
```

How can I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> NSMutableArray *eyelidDiagnosis[5];
> ```

You're confusing C and Objective-C here.  That's not how you declare an `NSMutableArray`, you're stuck somewhere between declaring a C array and an `NSMutableArray` object.

You need to instantiate an `NSMutableArray` object.  There are several ways of doing this, but this is one way:

```
NSMutableArray *eyelidDiagnosis = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: I'll accept the answer once the time limit expires.